# I would like to know how I can add an ngCordova plugin in IBM MobileFirst studio project?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ibm-mobilefirst, ngcordova

I would like to know how I would add an `ngCordova` plugin in IBM `MobileFirst` studio project?

I installed ngCordova but when I run :

```
> cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera
```

it tells me no cordova project structure found

Answer (score 1):

MobileFirst Studio projects do not support adding Cordova plug-ins using the Cordova CLI. What you are trying to do is not possible.

To add Cordova plug-ins, you may try to follow the instructions in the following blog post, however I do not believe these will be good for ngCordova: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2015/08/03/integrating-3rd-party-cordova-plug-ins/

I suggest to use MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.1 CLI in order to create a "pure" Cordova application instead, and try there.

Learn more here: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/c_developing_cordova_apps.html?lang=en

Comment: so you mean we can't use native component from Mobilefirst studio project ?

Comment: You can implement your own custom Cordova plug-in, but you won't be able to add it via the Cordova CLI: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/adding-native-functionality/